# Is My Lambda Calculus Grammar Unambiguous?

Tags: parsing, lambda, programming-languages, grammar, lambda-calculus

I am trying to write a small compiler for a language that handles lambda calculus. Here is the ambiguous definition of the language that I've found:

```
E → ^ v . E  | E E | ( E ) | v
```

The symbols ^, ., (, ) and v are tokens. ^ represents lambda and v represents a variable.
An expression of the form ^v.E is a function definition where v is the formal parameter of the function and E is its body. If f and g are lambda expressions, then the lambda expression fg represents the application of the function f to the argument g.

I'm trying to write an unambiguous grammar for this language, under the assumption that function application is left associative, e.g., fgh = (fg)h, and that function application binds tighter than ., e.g., (^x. ^y. xy) ^z.z = (^x. (^y. xy)) ^z.z

Here is what I have so far, but I'm not sure if it's correct:

```
E -> ^v.E | T
T -> vF | (E) E
F -> v | epsilon
```

Could someone help out?

Comment: 1) Unambiguous grammars are not the be-all-and-end-all.

Comment: 2) Why are you doing this by hand instead of with a (free) grammar tool, of which many are available free on the web?

Comment: Care to point me to a good one? I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: http://irony.codeplex.com/ is easy to learn.

Comment: @Pieter For many practical purposes, grammars *must* be unambiguous. One that more parse tree produces more than one interpretation, which might be OK when translating spoken languages, but that's no the norm.

Comment: @Apalala: On the contrary. I have built at least a half dozen DSL's over the years, and nary a one was unambiguous. I always had a few shift-reduce conflicts, and often one or 2 reduce-reduce conflicts, that were best left in and resolved external to the grammar. Slightly ambiguous grammars are often much easier to understand, and more efficient, than equivalent unambiguous grammars.

Comment: @Pieter If you're resolving possible ambiguities algorithmically, you're dong PEG, and not CFGs. CFGs have a theoretical definition, and ambiguity does too. That said, I'm all into your approach to the problem. That's why I wroke Grako.

Comment: @Apalala: I used to call it lex & yacc. These days I call it Irony.NET

Comment: @Pieter My current preference is against grammars expressed in non-grammar languages, because I think they obscure their clean, declarative nature. Time will tell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Between reading your question and comments, you seem to be looking more for help with learning and implementing lambda calculus than just the specific question you asked here. If so then I am on the same path so I will share some useful info.

The best book I have, which is not to say the best book possible, is [Types and Programming Languages](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) ([WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/47705787)) by Benjamin C. Pierce. I know the title doesn't sound anything like lambda calculus but take a look at [λ-Calculus extensions: meaning of extension symbols](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9548/268) which list many of the lambda calculi that come from the book. There is code for the book in [OCaml](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/checkers/) and [F#](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-tapl).

Try searching in [CiteSeerX](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/index;jsessionid=A4CC96D6F9ED308562E7AB17838776DC) for research papers on lambda calculus to learn more.

The best λ-Calculus evaluator I have found so far is:

[Lambda calculus reduction workbench](http://www.itu.dk/people/sestoft/lamreduce/lamframes.html) with info [here](http://www.itu.dk/people/sestoft/lamreduce/index.html).

Also, I find that you get much better answers for lambda calculus questions related to programming at [CS:StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lambda-calculus) and math related questions at [Math:StackExcahnge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lambda-calculus).

As for programming languages to implement lambda calculus you will probably need to learn a [functional language](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Functional_programming) if you haven't; Yes it's a different beast, but the enlightenment on the other side of the mountain is spectacular. Most of the source code I find uses a functional language such as ML or OCaml, and once you learn one, the rest get easier to learn.

To be more specific, [here](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-tapl/tree/master/untyped) is the source code for the untyped lambda calculus project, [here](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-tapl/blob/master/untyped/Parser.fsy) is the input file to an F# variation of YACC which from reading your previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850271/john-roberts?tab=questions) seems to be in your world of knowledge, and [here](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-tapl/blob/master/untyped/test.f) is sample input.

Since the grammar is for implementing a REPL, it starts with toplevel, think command prompt, and accepts multiple commands, which in this case are lambda calculus expressions. Since this grammar is used for many calculi it has parts that are place holders in the earlier examples, thus binding here is more of a place holder.

Finally we get to the part you are after

Note LCID is Lower Case Identifier

```
Term : AppTerm
     | LAMBDA LCID DOT Term 
     | LAMBDA USCORE DOT Term 

AppTerm : ATerm   
        | AppTerm ATerm

/* Atomic terms are ones that never require extra parentheses */
ATerm : LPAREN Term RPAREN 
      | LCID
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm a bit confused by the USCORE term in the grammar you provided - this doesn't seem to be part of the language I specified above. Also, the grammar you provided seems to be left-recursive, something I'm trying to avoid at the current moment. Could you comment on the validity of the grammar I wrote?

Comment: @JohnRoberts I will have to look into USCORE more before answering, I use some of the other grammars from the project. As Pieter Geerkens notes, don't get hung up on the grammar. A long time ago I did the same thing, now I conentrate on the AST and use one of many parsers, i.e. LL, LR, parser combinatros, hand build recursive descent, etc., for creating AST. In order to determine if your grammar is abmgiuous you need to specify they type of parser. This grammar is for an LR paser, but you seem to be after an LL grammar, no?

Comment: I'm looking for an LALR(1) parser grammar - I just do a check for LL(1) first as a quick verification. On second look at my grammar, it seems to me that it's unable to handle the case of a parenthesized expression at the end of a string, such as λx.λy.λz.x (y z) - do you see this as well?

Comment: Note: John and I used a chat room to continue this. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25426/lambda-calculus

Comment: The USCORE term is unnecessary for this example, but it's a common extension that programming languages use, and I guess wherever this code is copied from must support that extension. What it's used for is a variable name in places where you have to have a variable name, but you're never going to reference. For example, `^x. ^_. x` is a lambda expression which will return the first value passed to it and will throw away the second value passed to it. Using `_` for the second variable makes it obvious to the reader that the value will never be used.

Answer (score 2):

You may find the proof for a particular grammar's ambiguity in sublinear time, but proving that grammar is unambiguous is an NP complete problem. You'd have to generate every possible sentence in the language, and check that there is only one derivation for each.